# user defined variables on the heap getting destroyed in while loop

Tags: c++, function, linked-list, heap-memory

I an odd problem that i cant understand if someone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.I create my own linked list variables on the heap but when i go to add another variable to it they all get destroyed and i dont know why.
in my main i set up my variables like this
**main.cpp**

```
 Book* temp;  
    temp = bookSetUp();
```

this goes to a different cpp called functions which sets up the objects like this:
**functions.cpp**

```
      Book* bookSetUp()  
        {  
    //The items that populate the list  
    Book* a= new Book("A Tale of Two Cities", "Charles Dickens", "1", true);  
    Book* b= new Book("Lord of the rings", "J.R.R Tolkein", "2", true);  
    Book* c= new Book("Le Petit Prince", "Antoine de Saint-Exupéry", "3", true);  
    Book* d= new Book("And Then There Were None", "Agatha Christie", "4", true);  
    Book* e= new Book("Dream of the Red Chamber","Cao Xueqin","5", true);  
    Book* f= new Book("The Hobbit","J.R.R Tolkein","6", true);  
    //sets up the pointers between books  
    a->setPrev(NULL);  
    a->setNext(b);  
    b->setPrev(a);  
    b->setNext(c);  
    c->setPrev(b);  
    c->setNext(d);  
    d->setPrev(c);  
    d->setNext(e);  
    e->setPrev(d);  
    e->setNext(f);  
    f->setPrev(e);  
    f->setNext(NULL);  
    //sets up a temp pointer to a  
    Book* temp = a;  
    //returns the temp pointer to a  
    return temp;  
}
```

this works perfectly but later on when i go to add to the list again in the main using:
**main.cpp**

```
else if(checkRegUser(username, password, regUserList) == true)
    {
        int choice = 99;
        cout << "Welcome Registered user: "<< username << endl;
        while(choice != 0)
        {
            //this is so the print will start everytime as if you run it once print will be at NULL thereafter
            Book* print = temp;
            choice = options();
            if(choice == 1)
            {
                while(print!=NULL)
                {
                        cout<<"Name: "<<print->getName()<<endl<<"Author: "<<print->getAuthor()<<endl<<"ISBN: "<<print->getISBN()<<endl<<"Availability: "<<print->getAvail()<<endl;
                        cout<<endl;
                        print = print->getNext();
                }
                print = temp;
            }
            if(choice == 2)
            {
                search(temp);
            }
            if(choice == 3)
            {
                takeOut(temp);
            }
            if(choice == 4)
            {
                returnBack(temp);
            }
            if(choice == 5)
            {
                append(temp);
            }
            if(choice == 6)
            {
                cout<<"Sorry you have the privilege needed to use this function."<<endl;
            }
            if(choice == 7)
            {
                choice = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

My user defined variables get destroyed.  I debugged and they just disappeared i am not sure why!
Just in-case its needed here is my add() function because I feel It could be me missing something small or just making a disastrous mistake.  My add function is in the functions.cpp and I know all the links are working as I have everything else running apart from this
**functions.cpp**

```
Book* append(Book* tempParam)  
{  
   string title;  
   string author;  
   string isbn;  
   bool avail;  
   cout<<"What is the book called?"<<endl;  
   cin.clear();  
   cin.ignore();  
   getline(cin, title);     
   cout<<"Who is the author?"<<endl;  
   cin.clear();  
   cin.ignore();  
   getline(cin, author);  
   cout<<"What is the ISBN to be?"<<endl;  
   cin>>isbn;  
   Book* temp = new Book(title, author, isbn, true);
   Book* list = tempParam;int count;  
   while(list!=NULL)  
   {  
      if(list->getNext()==NULL&&list->getName()!=title)  
      {
         list->setNext(temp);  
         temp->setNext(NULL);  
         temp->setPrev(list);  
         cout<<"Your book has been added"<<endl;  
         cout<<temp->getName()<<temp->getAuthor()<<endl;  
      }  
      list = list->getNext();  
   }  
   tempParam = list;  
   return tempParam;  
}
```

My user defined classes are working perfectly its just when I go to add that my list gets destroyed any ideas??

Comment: Is it `add` or `append`? Could you prepare a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: I think we need more of main.

Comment: btw, it's not your error, but Book* append(Book* tempParam) doesn't work when you pass it an empty list.You should fix that.

Comment: You set `tempParam` to `list` and return it, right after you prove (via the `while` loop test) that `list` is NULL.

Comment: main has been updated accordingly and i will fix that @RichardPlunkett

Comment: How sure are you that the list is disappearing in append? 
I would add a print loop before an after the append, and to every visit to this section.
Code would be nicer to, if the "read a book from cin" idea wasn't in the same function as the "add a node to a list" idea.

Comment: if(list->getNext()==NULL&&list->getName()!=title)   when this condition is achieved you set list->setNext to new node and later you set list = list->getNext which is again NULL and you return this List set in tempParam. You need to check the logic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I think the error is found in this section of the code:

```
 list->setNext(temp);
```

You are "losing" the books because you didn't save them before you change list->next.*

The answer is incorrect because the conditional statement makes sure that it is the last element of the list. Sorry!

Comment: I thought this too but when i debug and go back to the main the list is still alive until it "completes" the loop at which point the list gets destroyed @AFM

Comment: @Dennington-bear - So the list still contains all the book when it exits out of the append function?

Comment: yes it is. I just checked there and now it works perfectly for some reason I dont know why as i have not changed anything! its Puzzling @AFM thanks for the help oh actually I do have one question though see the author input in the **append()**? is there any reason why if I type "Albert Einstein" it prints "lbert Einstein"

Comment: @Dennington-bear - it has something to do with cin.ignore(). I'd have to look up what it does.

Comment: list->setNext(temp);   is being done after checking list->getNext() is NULL, then how is this going to make lose of books??